# Rails5.1.1 includes + map function will extremely slow about 15 seconds

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

If user model includes multi tables and use map, its will really slow!!
Its could be about 11s~20s.

In console i watched the log print, its always slow when sql includes and after printed out sql query log finished its will go function very fast.

This function only do for data export to excel, so seldom to use lead to i don't want to use counter cache in this situation.

```
Benchmark.bm do |x| 
   x.report { 
     User.includes(:active_goal, :notification_setting, :reviews, 
     :comments, :answers, :quiz_answers).map(&:id) do |user|
        [
          user.active_goal.try(:name),
          user.notification_setting&.is_need_notify || false,
          user.reviews.size,
          user.comments.size,
          assignment_reviews(user.answers),
          right_ratio(user.quiz_answers)
        ]
      end
   }

   x.report { 
     User.includes(:active_goal, :notification_setting, :reviews, 
     :comments, :answers, :quiz_answers) 
    }
end

Benchmark::Tms: @real=14.244344999955501, @stime=0.45999999999999996, @total=13.05, @utime=12.59
Benchmark::Tms: @real=0.00010500004282221198, @stime=0.0, @total=0.0, @utime=0.0

@users.size = 887
QuizAnswer.all.size = 71386   
Goal.all.size = 1519    
NotificationSetting.all.size = 928    
Review.all.size = 10
Comment.all.size = 6664
Answer.all.size = 98

Ruby 2.4.1p111
```

By the way, these table i already did id index on.

Still don't know what problems it is.

Can someone help me please or share how can i speed up?

Comment: Well, it takes more time to get everything and do something to them, than to just get everything... You might have to be more specific in your example, to get good feedback, though (for example, your example could be improved by using pluck instead of map, maybe there is a similar optimization for your actual problem). FWIW, what version of ruby are you running, and how many records does that query return? I'm not seeing nearly as appreciable of a delay added by map using a similar example...

Comment: @BradWerth thanks your replied. I put more specific function and data size here, hope useful.

Answer (score -1):

use `.pluck(:id)` instead `.map(&:id)`
this is will be faster.

Comment: I need to use map here because i will do a series function in map block, just for example so i do map(&:id) here.